# Deserializing Json to Dictionary<string, List<string>> from the file?

Tags: c#

I converted a bunch of .txt files into a C# `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, then that into JSON, now I need to convert back into  `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.
This is my code to convert to JSON.

```
void WriteDictionaryAsJson(Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDict, string outputfilename)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, List<string>>));
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    js.WriteObject(ms, myDict); 

    StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(outputfilename);
    streamwriter.AutoFlush = true; 

    ms.Position = 0; 
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms); 
    streamwriter.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd()); 

    ms.Close(); 
    streamwriter.Close();
    sr.Close();

}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. If having problems then show a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for serialization can be greatly simplified as:

```
void WriteDictionaryAsJson(Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDict, string outputfilename)
{
    using (var outputFileStream = File.OpenWrite(outputfilename))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, List<string>>));
        js.WriteObject(outputFileStream, myDict);
    }
}
```

Deserialization is then very similar, you just replace *writes* with *reads*:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> ReadDictionaryFromJson(string inputfilename)
{
    using (var inputFileStream = File.OpenRead(inputfilename))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, List<string>>));
        return (Dictionary<string, List<string>>)js.ReadObject(inputFileStream);
    }
}
```